# Determining the object type which send as parameter

Tags: c#

I have three classes called Person, City and District, and some other.

I'm sending one of these three classes as a function parameter. I want to do an operation depends on which one of these three has been sended. How can I do that? All these three classes extends an Entity class.

Now it's like:

```
public void Insert (City newCity)
```

but I want it be like:

```
public void Insert (Entity e)
```

or something like that, and whichever it is (City or Person), I want to use it's properties.

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming polymorphism isn't possible (i.e. `e.DoTheThing(...);`), then perhaps `if(e is City) {...} else if (e is Person) {...} else if (e is District) {...}` ?

Comment: It's a little hard to guess what you're doing here, without more code. But look into the `is` or `as` operators to determine which type of type/class you're dealing with.

Comment: Why not just use three overloads of `Insert`? Doing type checking on the parameter of a method seems really odd rather than just having a different method for each entity...

Comment: @Christian.K I'm sipmly making a data base application with layered architecture, just for learning. And inPresentation layer, if user wants to add a Person, I take the information from user and use them to Business and Data layer. And determine which entity it is and use it in data layer to add it to data base.

Comment: @Chris I thought about that but, I have at least 4 operations like Update, Delete, Select ect. If I use overloads for other methods too, wouldn't it be a little complicated? Also, I want to learn the way I asked.

Comment: @emremrah: it really depends what those methods are doing. If each method basically consists of if blocks with unrelated code then you effectively have no more code if you were to split that up. If you actually have a lot of methods that all do this then I'd suggest splitting it up into three different classes (eg PersonRepository, CityRepository, etc.) that each have responsibility for one entity type. If you have one class responsible for doing things for three very different classes that is probably bad. If the classes have much more in common than their base class this makes more sense.

Comment: Also totally understand that you wanted to know how to do what you asked which is why I've not answered saying "don't do this". :)

Comment: As I understood from the comments, you need to understand in run-time what is the the type of the object and display it's properties to the user. Have you consider using **reflection**? I will use that if there is no relation between the types and no eventually you don't need to do changes when you add new types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it generic:

```
public void Insert<T>(T entity) where T: Entity
{

}
```

Now you can use all properties or methods of `Entity`. If you need to use properties or methods that only belong to the subtype, you have to cast it:

```
public void Insert<T>(T entity) where T: Entity
{
    if(entity is City)
    {
        City city = (City) entity;
        // ...
    }
    else if(entity is Person)
    {
        Person person = (Person) entity;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution but op wants to access their properties which wont work like this, you would need to cast. At least thats how I understand it

Comment: @EpicKip : You have no other option than to cast unless you overload the method. Though what's so wrong with casting??

Comment: @VisualVincent Well... because first it only said you can make it generic and that isnt the full fix. Now that the post has been updated it covers everything. I was saying casting wasn't covered

Comment: Yep. I will try this and some other solutions asap, then I'll inform you. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `is` and `as` operators in this way:

```
public void Insert(Entity e)
{
    if (e is Person)
    {
        Person tmp = e as Person;
        //do your code
    }
    else if (e is City)
    {
        City tmp = e as City;
        //do your code
    }
    else if(e is District)
    {
        District tmp = e as District;
        //do your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use inheritance and casting, something like this:

```
        public abstract class Entity
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        public class City : Entity
        {
            public string CityName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Person : Entity
        {
            public string PersonName { get; set; }
        }

        public class MethodHost
        {
            public void Insert(Entity e)
            {
                if (e is Person person)
                {
                    // Do something with person
                } else if (e is City cityName)
                {
                    // Do something with city
                }
            }
        }
```

P.S.: I'm using some new C# features here, if you are using an older version of C# you might need to do something like this:

```
var city = e as city
if(city != null)
{
    // Do something with city
}
```

You also can use the is in the if and cast inside the if-tags - but this isn't the most performant way as it casts two times instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be implementing different methods. If they have some general logic inside, just take it to the different method and call it.

```
public void Insert (City newCity)
{
    // TODO logic for City
}

public void Insert (Entity e)
{
    // TODO logic for Entity
}
```

Another way to do it is inheritance. If City can be derived from Entity than better do it this way:

```
public class Entity 
{
    public virutal void Insert (Entity e)
    {
        // TODO logic for Entity
    }
}

public class City : Entity
{
    public override void Insert (City city)
    {
        // TODO logic for City
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# 7.0 you could use Pattern Matching

```
public void Insert(Entity e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case Person p:
            Console.WriteLine("Insert Person");
            break;
        case City c:
            Console.WriteLine("Insert City");
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("<other>");
            break;
    }
}
```